# Scroll one page up in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, swift3

I have a big list of items displayed using UITableView, having variable heights.

Suppose first visible item is item #1000, how can I programmatically scroll exactly one page up?

Or how can I scroll up %80 of height?

Comment: Scroll your tableView to last visible cell's indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Select your `tableview` from interface builder. in `attribute inspector` check `paging enable` under the `scrollview`.

refer below screenshot!

[image]